# TestFlight Crash Reports / Logs disappeared from Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode, xcode7, crash-reports

The weirdest thing happened just now. From the Xcode organizer (Xcode 7.3.1) I was working through the crashes that came in through TestFlight. I then opened the Xcode project with the build that the crashes applied to (so I could get to the correct line number). Xcode crashed when trying to get to a line number. When I reopened Xcode all crash reports were gone for that particular build. The crash reports of older builds are still there, but for the newest build they are all gone. Tried reopening Xcode, shut down and restart, still the Organizer says 'No Crashes'.

Anyone have an idea what happened and, more importantly, how I can get these crash reports back? In iTunes Connect it still displays the number of crashes for that build. The build was released for external testing about a week ago so can't be the 72 hrs thing, even more so because crash reports were there for that build before the Xcode crash.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird. After restarting Xcode again and then doing a Product --> Clean all the crash reports magically reappeared again.